# SAFARI - giving child div height: 100% takes viewport height instead of the parent height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container and it is having two children. They are placed side by side using flex.
The second child is given a fixed height, so due to **align-items: stretch**(default flex property) the first child also stretches and takes up the height of the second child.

Now there is also a child(.child-a) of the first div and it only takes the space of its content only. But I want this child to take up all the height of its parent. So if I give **height: 100%** to that child, it works fine in chrome but in Safari it is taking viewport height. Is there any solution to this problem??

I have a simple HTML markup like below

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="child-a">Child of div a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">Div B</div>
</div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.a,
.b {
  width: 49%;
}

.a {
  background: yellow;
}

.child-a {
  background: red;
}

.b {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Try giving **.child-a**, height of 100% and then verify in safari and chrome both

**NOTE: working fine on codepen in safari as well as chrome**

Comment: I wrote an answer below. Can you tell if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me in safari, using a local index.html file. However, if it's still not working for you, you can also try giving `display: flex;` to `.child-a`:

```css
.child-a {
    background: red;
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I have also made an index.html file but it is not working...first div is taking viewport height

Comment: Did you try display: flex; on the child like I showed above? Because .child-a is a grandchild of the .container  display: flex; rule, you won't receive the advantages of display: flex;, at least consistently. So you need to add it to .child-a also.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `display: flex;` to the div 'a' and `flex : 1` to the child div 'child-a'.

**See the code below:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="child-a">Child of div a</div>
  </div>
  <div class="b">Div B</div>
</div>
<style>

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.a,
.b {
  width: 49%;
}

.a {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
}

.child-a {
  background: red;
  flex:1;
}

.b {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, that should work but why height 100% is causing the issue. Is it a known bug in safari?

Comment: I think it's because Safari ignore `align-items: stretch` set by default, when you add a height of 100% on a child.